# Firebase Rules - Restrict to a specific user or only if authorized?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have read all the google documentation on this and it still just doesn't seem to work.  I'm setting firebase rules and when I used the following, no problem I can read/write accordingly as the user is authenticated:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": { 
        ".write": "auth.uid != null",
        ".read": "auth.uid != null"
            },
     },
}
```

However, when I use the following, I get a permission denied:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": { 
      "$uid":{
        ".write": "auth.uid ===  $uid",
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid"
        },
     },
   },
}
```

Here is my database:

```
Users
 -tnRYoVw1duUKV30VgtOxUTvb5kb2
   FirstName: "Mike"
   LastName: "Smith"
   myuser: "msmith"
 -saUXlTt5ioLNB33Iii9rHCdq4ov6
   FirstName: "John"
   LastName: "Heart"
   myuser: "jheart"
```

Here is the read query from swift:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref?.child("Users").queryOrdered(byChild: "myuser").queryEqual(toValue: emailtextfield.text).observe(.value, with: { (snapShot) in
        if (snapShot.value! is NSNull) {
            print("nothing found")
        } else {
            let snapShotValue = snapShot.value as! [String:[String:Any]]
            Array(snapShotValue.values).forEach {
                let theFirstName = $0["FirstName"] as! String
                let theLastName = $0["LastName"] as! String
                self.firstName.text = theFirstName
                self.lastName.text = theLastName
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Appreciate any help you can provide in telling me where I've gone wrong folks.

Answer (score 2):

Those keys immediately under Users don't look like Firebase Auth UIDs.  They look like Realtime Database push IDs.  If they aren't actual UIDs, then your rule isn't going to work.

Comment: Thanks Doug.  Actually I tried it by adding the UID there just now and it still does not seem to work.  Either way - how would you do this if you are just using the random push ids?  Can you restrict the user from accessing data or is it simply not necessary since your query will only query data that matches the expected results?

Comment: I would not do this with random push IDs.  It's conventional to use the UID as the name of the node, as they are guaranteed to also be unique.

Comment: Thanks Doug.  I've modified the above to have the UID as the node.  Still get the error.  Thoughts?